# Считать и вывести вектор векторов

Tags: c++, vector

Считывает ввод, но не выводит вектор

```
int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > a;

    ll n;
    cin >> n;

    a.reserve(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i].reserve(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cin >> a[i][j];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cout << a[i][j] << " ";

        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: а у меня выводит... https://ideone.com/tQ6t1s

Comment: Вы в чем работаете? MSVS? Ctrl+F5 или system(“pause”) в конец

Comment: Как он вообще может работать если вы используете `reserve` а не `resize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C `reserve()` не работает потому что этот метод только выделяет память и никаких конструкторов не вызывает, а `resize()` создает заданное количество элементов т.е. вызывает конструкторы по умолчанию.